# Sql returns empty row on combinning primary key with another value in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am getting empty row on following sql

```
SELECT * FROM flyers WHERE fId='6' AND 'userId'='400'
```

MySQL returned an empty result set

```
(i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0004 sec)
```

But when i use

```
SELECT * FROM flyers WHERE fId='6'
```

Showing rows

```
0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0005 sec).
```

As i got my result and that is correct using only primary key.

But i does not know why mysql returns empty row on using AND with primary key.

Note:- fId is flyer table primary key.

Comment: if userid is int data type means remove single quotes userid=400

Comment: Did you check whether there ia an entry with userID=400

Comment: try remove the quotes 
SELECT * FROM flyers WHERE fId=6 AND userId=400

Comment: remove single quotes in userid column name and value because its column name not a value or string SELECT * FROM flyers WHERE fId='6' AND userId='400'

Comment: userId exists in the same row and its datatype is integer

Comment: 'Userid' is a string. Perhaps you meant \`userid\`

Comment: SELECT * FROM flyers WHERE fId=6 AND 'userId'=400

Comment: this also returns empty row

Comment: try my answers @smehsoud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you have only one mistake, which is that you used single quotes around `userId`. Use back-ticks instead or nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM flyers WHERE fId='6' AND userId='400'  

SELECT * FROM flyers WHERE fId=6 AND userId=400// safe not to use quotes
```

But I suggest not to use quotes around numbers for below reason.

The real issue comes down to type casting. When you put numbers inside quotes, it is treated as a string and MySQL must convert it to a number before it can execute the query. While this may take a small amount of time, the real problems start to occur when MySQL doesn't do a good job of converting your string.

For example, MySQL will convert basic strings like '123' to the `integer` 123, but will convert some larger numbers, like '`18015376320243459`', to floating point. Since floating point can be rounded, your queries may return inconsistent results.

Comment: Thanks for clarify the main reason.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Use back ticks for the column name not single quotes
2. If `userid` is int data type it means you have to remove single quotes `userid=400`
3. If `fid` is string it means `fID='6'`

   `SELECT * FROM flyers WHERE`fId`=6 AND`userId`=400`

Comment: what is the difference between 'userId' and userId means what it indicates to sql

Comment: @smehsoud, `userId` is an identifier (a column name here), `'userId'` is a string literal.

Comment: Thanks to all The conflict was on 'userId' and userId. Both fid and userId datatype is int but in my query fid was correct but i uses 'userId' instead of userId column name.I am confused on defining column name any mysql defining names link please